# How to link to a section in a One Page website with Revolution Slider

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, revolution-slider

I'm using a Revolution Slider on a one page wordpress website and I want to have a link inside the slider which will take the visitor to the 'contact us' section down the page. I'd rather not use the 'scroll below' option as this will not work properly on mobile devices.

I've added a div id="contact-info" in the raw html, but when I try to link to contact-info or #contact-info I get sent to a 404. What am I missing here?

I've added two screenshots: 
[one how I made the link in a button in the Revolution Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSMSm.png)
[one how I added the HTML in the page (through visual composer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkXLT.png)

Even if I change the link to any of the options mentioned above, the link still doesn't work.

Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: Try this, http://www.websitename.nl#contact-info @MilouvanKerkhof

Comment: Hi Parth, thanks for the suggestion, but it still redirects to a 404. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Just try to add #contact-info @MilouvanKerkhof

Comment: [screenshot](https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/636576/23lpxon7o65of38b58v3) take a look at this @MilouvanKerkhof

Answer (score 0):

Try to the Slide Editor > Link & Seo > Enable Link select "Disable".

then add #contact-info again. Hope can help!